# Mismatched Input-Ternary Operator (PineScript)

Tags: pine-script-v5

On using ternary operator in Plotchar() , the true condition is not fully recognized (in spite of placing it in "()" brackets).  Mismatched inpur error is given(refer image).
How to resolve this ?

Code:

```
k = ta.sma(...)
plotchar((k < 20) ? (xUp , "Go Long", "▲", location.bottom, color.lime, size = size.tiny) : na)
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator uses the ***series*** (xUp : na) only for conditionals,not the entire plotchar parameters.

```
k = ta.sma(...)
plotchar(k < 20 ? xUp: na , "Go Long", "▲", location.bottom, color.lime, size = size.tiny)
```